# How would I run a class from an already running separate class?

Tags: java, class, user-interface

I am trying to create a game of Tic Tac Toe that will have a menu that allows you to select which version of the game you would like to play but after hours of resarch and trying different things, I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
package TicTacToeGame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TicTacToeMenu extends TicTacToe2
{
  private JButton b1;
  private JButton b2;

  public TicTacToeMenu()
  {

    b1 = new JButton("Regular");
    b2 = new JButton("Colour");

    JTextField display = new JTextField();
    display.setEditable(false);
    display.setText("Welcome to TicTacToe! Choose the version you would like to play!");

    JPanel grid = new JPanel();
    grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    grid.add(b1);
    grid.add(b2);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(display,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(grid,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    b1.addActionListener(new ButtonResponse());
    b2.addActionListener(new ButtonResponse());
  }

  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    TicTacToeMenu frame = new TicTacToeMenu();    //create the custom frame
    frame.setSize(500,500);         //set the frame size
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);      //center on screen
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //make close button work
    frame.setVisible(true);         //make frame display 
  }

  class ButtonResponse implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    { 
      System.out.println("action detected");

      if(e.getSource() == b1)
      {
      }
      else if(e.getSource() == b2)
      {
      }
      else
      {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want it to run the first version of Tic Tac Toe (the class is Public class TicTacToe) when button b1 is clicked and version 2 of it (Public class TicTacToe) when b2 is clicked.

Comment: For starters, your menu class should most definitely not extend your game (TicTacToe2) class. That is abuse of inheritance and can lead to significant code problems, and so I advise you to keep them separate.

Comment: Next, I recommend that you try putting some code in your ActionListener's if blocks. We won't know where you may be stuck without seeing at least an attempt at something. Also, what do your game classes extend? JFrame (probably not a great idea)? JPanel (better)? Neither or nothing (this could work too, and work well)? Please tell us and show us more about these classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call TicTacToeMenu.main(), but it's a strange thing to do. More probably you want to just instantiate the object and let it run itself. It seems likely that you have an object model problem.